# Repeatedly printing the same node part, help in building a C# code

Tags: c#, class, nodes

I'm not much of a sophisticated programmer, and as home work I've been given a project in which I need to build a code that supposedly helps to manage a library or something like that.

The thing is, I've created a class for a list of books which will be stored in a `node<T>` format, but, after I've build the function to add a book to the list, something that I did wrong in the function "printchain" that's supposed to print all the books, makes it repeatedly print the same "book" over and over again.

Why it doesn't print the `node<T>` of books properly? Please refer mainly to the class "librarybooks" and the Main class as these are the places I'm dealing with this issue here.

```
namespace ConsoleApp7
{

    public class book
    {
        private int id;
        private string authorname;
        private string name;

        public book(int id, string authorname, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.authorname = authorname;
        }


        public string getname()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        public string getauthor()
        {
            return this.authorname;
        }
        public void setname(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setauthor(string authorname)
        {
            this.authorname = authorname;
        }
        public int getid()
        {
            return this.id;
        }
        public void setid(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public class author
    {

        private string name;
        private librarybooks autbooks;

        public author(string name, librarybooks autbooks)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.autbooks = autbooks;
        }
        public string getname()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setname(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public librarybooks getauthorsbooks()
        {
            return this.autbooks;
        }
        public void setauthorsbooks(librarybooks autbooks)
        {
            this.autbooks = autbooks;
        }

    }
    public class librarybooks
    {
        private node<book> books;

        public librarybooks()
        {
            this.books = null;
        }

        public node <book> Getbooks() { return books; }

        public void add(book book)
        {

            this.books = new node <book>(book, this.books);

        }

        public void printchain()
        {
            while (this.books.getNext().getValue() != null)
            {
                node<book> search = this.books;
                Console.WriteLine(search.getValue().getauthor() + " " + search.getValue().getid() + " " + search.getValue().getname());
                search = new node<book>(this.books.getNext().getValue(), this.books) ;
            }
        }
    }

    public class libraryauthors
    {
        private node<author> authors;

        public libraryauthors()
        {
            this.authors = null;
        }

        public void add(author author)
        {

            if (this.authors.getValue() == null)
            {
                this.authors.setValue(author);
                this.authors.setNext(null);
            }
            if (this.authors.getValue() != null)
            {
                this.authors.setNext(this.authors);
                this.authors.setValue(author);
            }

        }

    }

    public class node<T>
    {
        T value;
        node<T> next;

        public node(T x)
        {
            this.value = x;
            this.next = null;
        }
        public node(T x, node<T> next)
        {
            this.value = x;
            this.next = next;
        }
        public T getValue()
        {
            return this.value;
        }
        public void setValue(T value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public node<T> getNext()
        {
            return this.next;
        }
        public void setNext(node<T> next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            librarybooks ezer = new librarybooks();
            string str1, str2;
            int num1;
            Console.WriteLine("enter author");
            str1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter name");
            str2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter id");
            num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            book ezra=new book(num1,str2,str1);
            string str3, str4;
            int num2;
            Console.WriteLine("enter author");
            str3 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter name");
            str4 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter id");
            num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            book ezra2 = new book(num2, str4, str3);

            ezer.add(ezra2);
            ezer.add(ezra);

           ezer.printchain();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop currently looks like this:

```
while (this.books.getNext().getValue() != null)
{
    node<book> search = this.books;
    Console.WriteLine(...);
    search = new node<book>(this.books.getNext().getValue(), this.books) ;
}
```

It looks like you're trying to iterate through the list. But:

- You keep instantiating `search`, but not actually using it anywhere
- You don't really have a variable that keeps track of "where in the list am I"

An alternate approach might be to use a `List<book>`. It comes with C# by default, and you could then iterate through your List with a `foreach(book b : this.books)` loop. It'll save you from having to implement your own `node<T>` class.

Comment: see the thing is, we were specifically told to do it with node<T>, and I'm having trouble realizing how to declare  a variable that keeps track of "where in the list am I", am really stuck

Comment: There's a lot to implement here, but here's how I would do it in broad strokes: 1: make a class that represents a single book in your list; 2: make a class that represents the collection of books. The collection class should have some `int index` to count your current location in the list, as well as `hasNext()` and `getNext()` methods. `getNext()` should return the `index`-th value in your collection, and also increment this value.